# How do I automatically assign the id of saved entities?

Tags: nosql, ravendb

Let's say I have the following structure of an entity I'm trying to save in a RavenDB v2.0 document store using the client side API.

```
public class Instance
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

If I'm creating 10-20 instances and I want to save the entity id for each entity respectively. What I can see in the documentation on the site is that you can retrieve the id of an entity after you call the `session.SaveChanges()` method, but that would mean that I need to call this method for each entity item that I have.

What's a best practice to use here? Is there any way that the client API would automatically save the entity id in a field of the entity class (is there an attribute for that maybe)?

Comment: Just to clarify Fitzchack's answer - Change your property to `Id` instead of `ID` and it is populated after `Store`.  You don't have to wait until `SaveChanges`.

Comment: I did..I created a `public` `string` property named `Id` with `{get; set;}` but it's still `null` after `Store`.

Comment: Unless you're trying to set it yourself, it should be populated.  Post a sample if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

With the default conventions RavenDB set the ID value after calling `session.Store(item)`, using an HiLo algorithm in order to generate the ID on the client without reaching to the server for each ID assignment. The ID is available on a property called "Id" can you can configure to look also for property named property.